# Not able to connect to MQ Server from MQ Client

Tags: c

In c, I tried to connect to the MQ server from the same Unix server where MQ server is installed and it is getting connected and putting message into the queue but the same thing if I am trying from MQ Client (from another development server) it is throwing error message:

> MQCONN ended with reason code 2195.

Following is sample:

```
 // Libraries included
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>     
#include <cmqc.h>          
#include <cmqxc.h>
```

Following are the variables which i declared and defined to connecing to MQ Server:
  // Variable declarations.

```
   MQCNO   Connect_options = {MQCNO_DEFAULT};       /* MQCONNX options           */ 

   MQCD    ClientConn = {MQCD_CLIENT_CONN_DEFAULT}; /* Client connection channel */ 

   MQHCONN  Hcon;                   /* connection handle             */ 

   MQHOBJ   Hobj;                   /* object handle                 */ 

   MQLONG   CompCode;               /* completion code               */ 

   MQLONG   Reason;                 /* reason code                   */ 

   MQOD     od = {MQOD_DEFAULT};    /* Object Descriptor             */ 

   MQMD     md = {MQMD_DEFAULT};    /* Message Descriptor            */ 

   MQPMO    pmo = {MQPMO_DEFAULT};  /* put message options           */ 

   MQLONG   O_options;              /* MQOPEN options                */ 

   MQLONG   C_options;              /* MQCLOSE options               */ 

   char     QMgrName[MQ_Q_MGR_NAME_LENGTH+1]; 

   char     QName[MQ_Q_NAME_LENGTH+1]; 

   char     channelName[MQ_CHANNEL_NAME_LENGTH+1]; 

   char     hostname[1024]; 

   MQLONG   buflen;                 /* buffer length                 */ 

   char     TempBuf[1024] = "MQPutdata:This is a simple test message.";
```

Following are the other variables defined to call MQCONNX function:
printf("MQPutdata started\n");

```
strncpy(QMgrName, argv[1], MQ_Q_MGR_NAME_LENGTH); 
   QMgrName[MQ_Q_MGR_NAME_LENGTH] = '\0'; 

   strncpy(channelName, argv[2], MQ_CHANNEL_NAME_LENGTH); 
   channelName[MQ_CHANNEL_NAME_LENGTH] = '\0'; 

   strncpy(hostname, argv[3], 1023); 
   hostname[1023] = '\0'; 

   strncpy(QName, argv[4], MQ_Q_NAME_LENGTH); 
   QMgrName[MQ_Q_NAME_LENGTH] = '\0';
```

Here I am setting  required values for MQCONNX function

```
   strncpy(ClientConn.ConnectionName, 
           hostname, 
           MQ_CONN_NAME_LENGTH); 

   strncpy(ClientConn.ChannelName, 
           channelName, 
           MQ_CHANNEL_NAME_LENGTH);
```

Now I am calling the MQCONNX function in this way:

```
 Connect_options.ClientConnPtr = &ClientConn; 
  Connect_options.Version = MQCNO_VERSION_2; 


   MQCONNX(QMgrName,                
           &Connect_options,         
           &Hcon,                   
           &CompCode,               
           &Reason);
```

I compiled with the following optpions but nothing is working:

```
 1. cc -H -I/export/home/aupadhya/mqm/inc -L/opt/mqm/lib64 -o MQPutdata.exe MQPutdata.c -lmqic 

 2. cc -H -I/export/home/aupadhya/mqm/inc -L/opt/mqm/lib64 -o MQPutdata.exe MQPutdata.c -lmqic -lmqmcs -lsocket

 3. cc -H -I/export/home/aupadhya/mqm/inc -L/opt/mqm/lib64 -o MQPutdata.exe MQPutdata.c -lmqic -lmqmcs -lmqmzse -lsocket
```

Comment: When asking question about compiler and/or linker errors, then please provide a *complete* and *unedited* error log. So please edit your question to include that (just copy-paste all the error messages). I also recommend you to please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: If you have *other* problems, then you need to describe the actual and wanted behavior. If you have crashes, then you should run in a debugger (remember to build with debug information with the `-g` flag) and post the function call stack (at least).

Comment: And please check your post formatting. (For example, don't indent normal text, only code, and code should be indented *four* spaces not three.)